# How to differentiate a multivariable function $S = S(\xi, \delta, \epsilon)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fluid-dynamics

Consider the equation $-cS' + SS' + \delta S''' - \epsilon S'' = 0$. The function $S = S(\xi, \delta, \epsilon)$, where $\xi = x - ct$ satisfies this ODE. In this case, ' denotes differentiation with respect to $\xi = x - ct$.

I am trying to verify this result by performing the differentiation myself but I don't really understand how to differentiate S. Should I apply the chain rule or the product rule?

This result is from a research paper I am currently reading and attempting to understand.

Comment: A much more useful piece of information would be to say *which* research paper you are reading. And what exactly is it that you're trying to verify? Is there some PDE involved, and you're looking for travelling wave solutions to it?

Comment: The paper is called "Travelling-wave solutions to the Korteweg-de Vries-Burgers equation." However that part is not really relevant. I am simply trying to understand how to differentiate the function S

Comment: Well, my point is that it's not clear from your question what you (or the authors) are trying to do, and someone with access to the paper might be able to tell from there what's going on. So it may very well be relevant information (and also include the authors, and a link if possible). But if I may guess, you have a PDE for $u(x,t)$ and want to see when $u(x,t) = S(x-ct)$ satisfies it, and therefore you want to compute $u_t$, $u_x$, $u_{xx}$, etc., in terms of $S'$, $S''$, etc., in which case it's just the multivariable chain rule.

Comment: So (if my guess is correct) the question is not really how to differentiate the function $S$, it's how to differentiate the function $u$ and get the result in terms of $S$.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Comment too long to be edited in the comments section :

$$-cS' + S\,S' + \delta \,S''' - \epsilon\,S'' =0\tag 1$$
Since you wrote "$\:\:'$ denotes differentiation with respect to $\xi\:$ " the variable is  $\xi\text{ and } c,\delta,\epsilon$ are parameters. So the ODE might be :
$$-c\frac{dS}{d\xi}+S(\xi)\frac{dS}{d\xi}+\delta\frac{d^3S}{d\xi^3}-\epsilon\frac{d^2S}{d\xi^2}=0$$
This ODE is not linear. Solving it analytically would not be elementary but requiring high level maths.

Probably there is a typo in Eq.$(1)$

For maths at student level the equation might be :
$$-c\frac{dS}{d\xi}+S(\xi)+\frac{dS}{d\xi}+\delta\frac{d^3S}{d\xi^3}-\epsilon\frac{d^2S}{d\xi^2}=0$$
with some coefficients for $S(\xi)$ and/or for $\frac{dS}{d\xi}$ that one cannot guess.

Check the wording of the problem and the equation.

Comment: The ODE given is correct. I think I was hoping there would be a clear cancelling out as there sometimes is with ODEs but clearly that is not the case here. However it is good to see that my differentiating was not the issue; rather that solving the ODE is beyond my current knowledge.